# How to enhance the flow to handle the duplicate requests and instead of moving to BO queue?

Tags: messagebroker

How to enhance the flow to handle the duplicate requests and instead of moving to BO queue? We have multiple cases receiving on daily basis, where the customer is sending multiple requests within seconds and moving to BO incase of duplicate request.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the message is being backed out indicates to me that your flow is already somehow detecting the duplicate and must be throwing an exception somewhere.

If you can identify this particular exception then instead of throwing back all the way to the input node and initiating a rollback you can handle the exception in a branch of the flow wired up to the catch terminal. For example perhaps by logging the message id to a log of duplicates or similar.

The tricky part will be ensuring that you can adequately identify the exception so that you are not doing the wrong failure processing for other types of failures.